# cake php mail function helper not found

Tags: email, cakephp, helper, view-helpers

3 I am getting error in sending mail.here below i have mentioned my code.

in controller file
var $components = array('RequestHandler', 'Filter','Image','Email','Captcha','RandomHelper');

then in my function i have write
$this->Email->from = $from;

```
$this->Email->subject = 'Approval Form: ';


$this->Email->delivery = 'debug';


$this->Email->template = 'adminemail';


$this->Email->sendAs = 'html';


$this->Email->send();
```

i dont want to send mail using SMTP. when i run this code the error is for missing helper file it tel me "rror: The helper file app/views/helpers/email.php can not be found or does not exist." Anyone can pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email is not a helper, it was a component in 1.3 and in 2.0 there is CakeEmail

You do not load helpers in the component property, use public $helpers = array('MyHelper');

Helpers are loaded without the "Helper" suffix in the $helpers property.

It looks like you do not have any idea of what MVC is or what the difference between helpers and components are. I suggest you to read about MVC and CakePHPs different parts like what the difference is between a component and a helper and a behavior for example.

Comment: hey finally i solved that error .. that is appear because i have write $helpers = array('RequestHandler', 'Filter','Image','Email','Captcha','RandomHelper');

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to CakePHP 2.x Documentation about [CakeMail](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html) or to the CakePHP 1.3 Documentation about the [Email Core Component](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1283/Email) if you are using this version of CakePHP.

(Cake)Email has never been a Helper, [Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html) are for [Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html), [Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html) are for [Controllers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html), [Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html) for [Models](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html).

They allow you to externalize part of the logic to reuse it somewhere else.

In [Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html), you can also use [Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements) for elements you use often.